# Suddenly inaccessible local drivess on several Windows Server 2016 / ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-server-2016

I installed a new ESXi 6.5 with Server 2016 machines.

After adding one more virtual harddisk to one of the servers I couldn't access it. It was shown in the explorer but was not accessible (access denied). I rebooted the windows server and after that **the other local drives became also inaccessible** (except the system drive).

Same on the next Windows server, after rebooting the local drives became also inaccessible (except the system drive).

[image]

The server were running since two weeks without any problems.

What I checked:

- No NTFS permission problem: Taking onwership and granting explicit rights didn't solve the problem (like: [Domain Admins group denied access to d: drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/292483/domain-admins-group-denied-access-to-d-drive))
- checking eventlog
- checking esx logs
- checking windows updates: no new updates since 5 days (server were rebooted in this time)
- No antivirus is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution: [Data drive is inaccessible after Windows GPO update](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2097525?lang=en_US). The servers became also added to the domain. The revomable storage policy blocked the access.

Quote:

> - To resolve this issue, remove the affected Computer from Group Policy objects (GPO) set to restrict read and write access on removable devices.
> - To remove the affected Computer from Group Policy objects (GPO) set to restrict read and write access on removable devices, navigate to
>     Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access >All Removable Storage classes and deny all access