# AWS EC2: All users Lost Access to D:\ - Access Denied

Tags: windows, active-directory, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drive

I have seen a number of similar problems reported in my searches, leading me to a number of questions including:

[Access to D drive lost even as an administrator (Windows 10)](https://serverfault.com/questions/962380/access-to-d-drive-lost-even-as-an-administrator-windows-10)
[Domain Admins group denied access to d: drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/292483/domain-admins-group-denied-access-to-d-drive)

I am seeing the same symptoms intermittently on a number of servers that I work with, including one today that occurred while working on it.

In our case, we are working with AWS EC2 instances, with our D:\ being a separate volume.

We have tried changing permissions / taking ownership to no avail. When this issue occurred previously, we also tried adding a new volume to the instance, but that too, could not be written to. Making changes to the drive via a command prompt started as Administrator also fails.

The only solution that we have found is pulling the server from the domain, rebooting, re-adding to the domain and then after a final reboot, we are again able to access the drive.

To add a detail, what I noticed today was that I was trying to save a file, was unable to, so I just went to the D:\ & tried creating a folder. It immediately created 3 new folders (New Folder, New Folder (2) etc...), and from that point on, nothing could be created/changed. This behavior was also seen by one of my colleagues. We've seen this on Windows Server 2012 and 2016

Thanks!